# Problem on exiting application called using JNI from Delphi

Tags: delphi, java-native-interface

I am calling a java function in Delphi 7 using JNI. When start button click the java application loads and when stop button clicks the java application exits. But my problem is that when I click stop button, the java application and the delphi application exits. I need to exit the java application only and not the delphi application.

```
var
  exit_code: Integer;
  Runtime  : TJavaRuntime;
begin
  exit_code := 0;
  Runtime.CallExit(exit_code);
end
```

Comment: Looks like `java.lang.System.exit()` is terminating the process too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Runtime.exit()` calls `Runtime.halt()` which forcibly terminates the JVM process. Unfortunately the JVM (`jvm.dll`) is running in the same process as your application, so the call of `Runtime.exit()` terminates your application.